# How to fix 'Property 'setTileUrlFunction' does not exist on type TileSource' error while using openlayers with typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, openlayers, typescript-typings

I am trying to use openlayers in react js project with typescript. But getting an error saying `Property 'setTileUrlFunction' does not exist on type 'TileSource'`

I installed ol using `yarn add ol`. Initially I was getting `declarations file could not be found` error When importing `import Map from 'ol/Map'`. I installed `@types/openlayers` which did not seem to help at all. Then I did `yarn add @types/ol`. That removed the declarations errors. But now I'm getting the above mentioned error when using `setTileUrlFunction`.

This is the component I wrote. I am trying to render a high resolution image using openlayers. Image taken from [openseadragon website](https://openseadragon.github.io/).

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Zoomify from 'ol/source/Zoomify';
import Tile from 'ol/layer/Tile';
import Map from 'ol/Map';
import View from 'ol/View';

export default class EditProject extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    const imgWidth = 7026;
    const imgHeight = 9221;

    const zoomifyUrl = 'https://openseadragon.github.io/example-images/highsmith/highsmith_files/{z}/{x}_{y}.jpg';

    const source = new Zoomify({
      url: zoomifyUrl,
      size: [imgWidth, imgHeight],
      crossOrigin: 'anonymous'
    });

    const layer = new Tile({ source })

    layer.getSource().setTileUrlFunction(function(tileCoord: any) {
      let z: any = tileCoord[0]+8
      let x: any = tileCoord[1]
      let y: any =  -(tileCoord[2]+1)
      return zoomifyUrl.replace(
        '{z}', z
      ).replace(
        '{x}', x
      ).replace(
        '{y}', y
      );
    });

    const extent = [0, -imgHeight, imgWidth, 0];

    const map = new Map({
      layers: [layer],
      target: 'mapContainer',
      view: new View({
        resolutions: layer.getSource().getTileGrid().getResolutions(),
        extent
      })
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div ref="mapContainer"></div>
    )
  }
}
```

The image was not rendering because of the error.

Comment: The layer definition should be `layer = new Tile({ source: source })`

Comment: @Mike In es6, if both the key and value have same name, we can you the shorthand `{ source }` instead of `{source: source}`. I don't think that is the cause for the problem. Anyway, I changed it to `layer = new Tile({ source: source })` and checked. Still getting the error.

Comment: If the result of `getSource()` is typed as `TileSource` (which doesn't support `setTileUrlFunction`) and TypeScript doesn't recognise the methods of its subclasses you would need to use the subclass objects directly. 
 In this case you could use the original source object  `source.setTileUrlFunction( ... );`

Comment: I declared layer with type any - `const layer: any = new Tile({ source })` and it worked.